# K value vs Accuracy in KNN

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour, accuracy, precision-recall

am trying to learn KNN by working on Breast cancer dataset provided by UCI repository. The Total size of dataset is 699 with 9 continuous variables and 1 class variable.

I tested my accuracy on cross-validation set. For K =21 & K =19. Accuracy is 95.7%.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=21)
neigh.fit(X_train, y_train) 
y_pred_val = neigh.predict(X_val)
print accuracy_score(y_val, y_pred_val)
```

But for K= 1, I am getting Accuracy = 97.85% K = 3, Accuracy = 97.14

I read

> Choice of k is very critical – A small value of k means that noise will have a higher influence on the result. A large value make it computationally expensive and kinda defeats the basic philosophy behind KNN (that points that are near might have similar densities or classes ) .A simple approach to select k is set k = n^(1/2). ([Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568897/value-of-k-in-k-nearest-neighbour-algorithm/11569262#11569262))

Which value of K should I consider for my model. Can you guys elaborate the logic behind it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would consider k as a hyperparameter of your algorithm and chose the best possible hyperparameter by crossvalidation. There is no valid rule of thumb for chosing k, since the ideal k varies depending on domain and data.

Answer (score 1):

Nikolas is right. The way to go about it is to do something like cross validation with different Ks, and chose the k that minimizes the cross validation error.

Comment: Hi @filipe
I tested accuracy on cross-validation data and these results are tested on that data only.

Comment: Hi Rahul. In that case, I guess it stands to reason, that K=1 is the value that leads to the best generalization accuracy. 
However, maybe another concern is the issue of class imbalance. If you have a class imbalance (one of the classes is far more frequent than others), then "Accuracy" may not be the best error metric.

Answer (score 0):

Given that its cancer data (which inherently has class imbalance), F1 score (not accuracy) will be the correct metric to use. Here's wiki for more on F1 [score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score). It basically lets you chose how you want to relatively weigh Precision and Recall.

Small changes to K in training set can lead to large changes in decision boundary so you'll need to cross validate and see if the results generalize well.